# How to calculate the closest latitude longitude for an entire column?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, latitude-longitude

I have a list of latlongs of location accidents and want to see what the closest police station was to each of these accidents. Currently the list of latlongs of the accidents are in two separate columns using pandas (I'm sorry, I'm very new to python so I might be using words incorrectly). The latlongs of the police station are currently in a separate json file. My current goal is to create a new column (or file) in which the latlongs appear of the nearest police station. Ideally it'd be the corresponding name, but that's a bridge I'll cross when I come to it.

I've looked at how other people did it but couldn't come further than asking the location for only one pair of latlongs and not all at the same time.

```py
from math import cos, asin, sqrt

def distance (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p = 0.017453292519943295
    a = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p)*cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p)) / 2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))

def closest(data, v):
    return min(data, key=lambda p: distance(v['lat'],v['lon'],p['lat'],p['lon']))

#these are the latlons of the police stations
tempDataList = [{"lat": 52.003181, "lon": 4.353068}, 
    {"lat": 52.089416, "lon": 4.377340},
    {"lat": 52.019911, "lon": 4.426602},
    {"lat": 52.054457, "lon": 4.388764},
    {"lat": 52.044536, "lon": 4.332631},
    {"lat": 52.072910, "lon": 4.274784},
    {"lat": 52.066099, "lon": 4.298664},
    {"lat": 52.070030, "lon": 4.317355},
    {"lat": 52.052636, "lon": 4.289576},
    {"lat": 52.060829, "lon": 4.318683},
    {"lat": 52.075680, "lon": 4.306810},
    {"lat": 52.040353, "lon": 4.256946},
    {"lat": 52.089381, "lon": 4.345599},
    {"lat": 52.111719, "lon": 4.283909},
    {"lat": 52.055222, "lon": 4.233827},
    {"lat": 52.046393, "lon": 4.253105},
    {"lat": 52.144177, "lon": 4.405549},
    {"lat": 51.987035, "lon": 4.199314},
    {"lat": 52.061650, "lon": 4.486572}]

v = {'lat': 52.103167, 'lon': 4.317532}
print(closest(tempDataList, v))
```

This is where I fail because I simply don't know how to get `v` to be two columns and to put it into a new column.

I'm hoping for a column in which the latlong of the nearest police station are shown.
Sometimes I run into the problem `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can see how to convert your list of indices to numpy arrays, on which you can afterwards operate without having to loop through every element.

```py
import numpy as np
# numpy allows you to work with arrays; math only works with scalars
from numpy import cos, arcsin as asin, sqrt

def distance (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    """Return the distances between all accidents (lat1,lon1)
    and all police stations (lat2,lon2) as a 2-dimensional array
    """
    # add dummy dimension to p
    lat2 = lat2[:,None]
    lon2 = lon2[:,None]
    p = 0.017453292519943295
    a = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p)*cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p)) / 2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))

def closest(*args):
    """Returns the index (counting from zero) of the closest
    police station for every accident.
    """
    return np.argmin(distance(*args), axis=0)


tempDataList = [{"lat": 52.003181, "lon": 4.353068},
    {"lat": 52.089416, "lon": 4.377340},
    {"lat": 52.019911, "lon": 4.426602},
    {"lat": 52.054457, "lon": 4.388764},
    {"lat": 52.044536, "lon": 4.332631},
    {"lat": 52.072910, "lon": 4.274784},
    {"lat": 52.066099, "lon": 4.298664},
    {"lat": 52.070030, "lon": 4.317355},
    {"lat": 52.052636, "lon": 4.289576},
    {"lat": 52.060829, "lon": 4.318683},
    {"lat": 52.075680, "lon": 4.306810},
    {"lat": 52.040353, "lon": 4.256946},
    {"lat": 52.089381, "lon": 4.345599},
    {"lat": 52.111719, "lon": 4.283909},
    {"lat": 52.055222, "lon": 4.233827},
    {"lat": 52.046393, "lon": 4.253105},
    {"lat": 52.144177, "lon": 4.405549},
    {"lat": 51.987035, "lon": 4.199314},
    {"lat": 52.061650, "lon": 4.486572}]

# first get lat and lon into arrays
lat, lon = np.transpose([[i['lat'],i['lon']] for i in tempDataList])

# I'm making up the police stations here. Say 5 police stations.
# you should load the actual data in your problem. My station locations
# are randomly located near the first 5 accidents
npolice = 5
# for reproducibility
np.random.seed(3)
plat = lat[:npolice] + np.random.normal(0, 0.02, npolice)
plon = lon[:npolice] + np.random.normal(0, 0.02, npolice)

index = closest(lat, lon, plat, plon)
# index = array([3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2])
```

So the nearest police station locations would be

```py
nearest = {'lat': plat[index], 'lon': plon[index]}
```

and you can use `index` to access, say, the name or address of each police station if you've also stored those.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, I might have been slightly confusing with the formulation of the question. The _tempDataList_ is the list of the police station coordinates. 
I have a separate df with pandas that contains two columns 'lat' and 'lon' with which I'd like to match to the _tempDataList_. Is there a way to compare the latlons of the df with those in the _tempDataList_?
Either way, thank you so much!

Comment: well in that case if you keep everything else the same you just need to change the `axis=0` argument in `closest` to `axis=1`. Alternatively, pass the police stations as `lat1`, `lon1` and the accident locations as `lat2`,`lon2`. Either way, you can test things by making sure that the number of police stations is different from the number of accidents (for testing purposes) and making sure that the length of the output of `closest` is equal to the number of accidents, not police stations